# How to determine if an email is successfully delivered instantly

Tags: coldfusion, railo, cfmail

An app is designed to be installed on a user's computer, hence, an email function from the app would very much depends on the user's ISP service.  Port 25 may be open or may be blocked.

When I use standard code for mail ua including port 25, it seems to deliver the email, however, for  some user whose ISP blocks port 25 email does not go through.  I'd like to have a reliable way to determine if port 25 fails to deliver email Instantly and then try to use another port to send email.  In other words, I'd like to leverage two ports, if port X fails then automatically switch to port Y.  Doable?

Btw, the web server side scripting language I'm using is Adobe ColdFusion's sibling, Railo, and the specific tag is CFMAIL.  As mentioned above, wrapping CFTRY around CFMAIL does not help for this purpose.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple factors in determining if your message gets delivered.

1)  When you send your message with CFMAIL, you can either specify a mail server in the cfmail tag, or use the server default.  When the tag is executed, coldfusion/railo will try to access that server.  If the server is unavailable or blocked, your message will go to the coldfusion/railo undeliverable folder.  The only way to check that is to write a script to monitor the undeliverable folder and its content.

2) IF coldfusion/railo successfully connect to the SMTP server and attempts to hand off the email, your notifications would come from the SMTP server rather than coldfusion/railo.  The message would be sent from the SMTP server to the `failto=""` path, or the `from=""` if not specified.  That email would be notified for "mailbox does not exist", "relay not allowed", "user over their mailbox limit", etc....

If you need to monitor those bounces, you could create a separate email account for the failto="" and use CFPOP to monitor the email account for bounces.

Also, if you use a company like sendgrid for your outgoing SMTP server, they will provide an API to monitor bounces, opt outs, spam complaints, etc...